# Loading text file into jTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, bufferedreader

i'm using Java to make a library for my films stored my HDD's. I made 1 method to save all content that i type i jTable and im calling this method on button event (mouse click) it worked well and i got a nice text file. Then i made a method to load text file to my table i dont gets any error while compiling but when i run application and click on button to load table Nothing happens, i have added prints in to method just to see if method runs and it dose.

Here is my code for saving table to a text file (working method):

```
public void saveTable()throws Exception
{
  BufferedWriter bfw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Data.txt"));
   for(int i = 0 ; i < jTable2.getColumnCount() ; i++)
  {
bfw.write(jTable2.getColumnName(i));
bfw.write("\t");
  }

    for (int i = 0 ; i < jTable2.getRowCount(); i++)
  {
    bfw.newLine();
    for(int j = 0 ; j < jTable2.getColumnCount();j++)
     {
       bfw.write((String)(jTable2.getValueAt(i,j)));
        bfw.write("\t");;
        }
       }
      bfw.close();
         }
```

Here is my text file :

```
Movies  Map HDD 
Test    no  1
```

Here is my load method :

```
public void loadTable()throws Exception{
    DefaultTableModel tm = (DefaultTableModel) jTable2.getModel();
   BufferedReader bfw = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Data.txt"));

  for (int i = 0 ; i < jTable2.getRowCount(); i++)
  {
tm.addRow(new Object[] { bfw.readLine()});
  }
  bfw.close();
}
```

Did i miss understood something of BufferReader content?

Comment: Consider creating and posting an [sscce](http://sscce.org). Also consider putting in just a little effort to try to format well the code you've posted here. It is greatly appreciated when you do this and will help us to understand and help you better. Please remember -- we're all volunteers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to split each line into it's three values before adding it to the row.

```
tm.addRow( bfw.readLine().split("\t") );
```

Of course that doesn't do any data type conversion, but if all you want is series of Strings that'll work.

Probably would rather do the following:

```
while( (line = bfw.readLine() ) != null ) {
   tm.addRow( line.split("\t") );
}
```

In the for loop your table isn't populated yet so that'll probably be zero and nothing happens.  This reads lines until the file data is done, and adds it to the table.

Comment: Thank you for quick answer it worked. I'm happy that i at least was on right way.